# JTree editor component hides the JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtable, size, jtree

I've create a customized JTree that renders some nodes as JTable, but when trying to edit/select the table (left click on the node) the table resizes and hides the JTree behind it.
I find it curious becaus ESC closes the editor (JTable) and shows the tree again. I feel like this is a feature ?? But what I want is to be able to interact with the tables as it is rendered with the tree visible.

So far I've overriden:

- AbstractLayoutCache.NodeDimensions.getNodeDimensions(....) : compute the dimension I want the tree node to be drawn in.
- TreeCellRenderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(...) : creates the different components to be rendered (and edited) with the correct preferred size.
- the Cell Editor that extends AbstractCellEditor and implements
  TreeCellEditor : it calls the renderer to get the edit component (the exact same component).
- ComponentAdapter to tie everything together.
- ComponentAdapter.getNodeDimensions to compute the node drawing area.

I've noted that:

- The VariableHeightLayoutCache does not seem affect the sizes of the shown elements (verified throught debugging) as planned.
- The JTree.paint is not called when the editor component is drawn.

Ideally, the editor component should be drawn over (or replace) the rendrer component to make the interactions intuitive.

Comment: Consider giving us a [mcve] in order to get more help.

Comment: Thank you, I failed to reproduce the issue on a minimalistic example. And that led me to a solution.
The issue was the layout manager: if you set a layout manager for a JTree it only applies when editing the components, hence the layout change when a component is clicked.

**Solution :** make sure the layout manager of the JTree is null.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you George Z., I failed to reproduce the issue on a minimalistic example. And that led me to a solution. The issue was the layout manager: if you set a layout manager for a JTree it only applies when editing the components, hence the layout change when a component is clicked.

**Solution :** make sure the layout manager of the JTree is null.

Comment: *"**Solution :** make sure the layout manager of the JTree is null."* If setting the layout manager to `null` is the answer, it must have been a silly question. Down voting the Q & the A to warn others off this approach.